# How to do smoothing of data with low counts?

Tags: count-data, smoothing

We are a facing a problem of fluctuating shares for each week for the products we are studying due to low counts. e.g. If we have 4 products and for each one we have say like 5,8,3,6 details and we divide by total to get share of each. But due to low counts this share is fluctuating, we tried rolling 4 weeks, but if we study product share by one further classification this share is still low sometimes, especially when new products are launched. How do we handle this kind of fluctuation and make it more stable?

Comment: You could try [additive smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_smoothing).